# What are all the different HLSL sampler types for?

Tags: directx, direct3d, shader, hlsl

I'm working with DX9/SM3 at the moment, and the MSDN documentation on [HLSL samplers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509644.aspx) seems to be sorely lacking in explaining how to use the different sampler types. What's worse is they try to cover DX9 and DX10 in a single article, so they jumble together all the keywords:

> sampler *Name* = *SamplerType* { Texture = <*texture_variable*>; [*state_name* = *state_value*;] ... };

...

> *SamplerType*
>
> > [in] The sampler type, which is one of the following: *sampler*, *sampler1D*, *sampler2D*, *sampler3D*, *samplerCUBE*, *sampler_state*, *SamplerState*.
> >
> > Differences between Direct3D 9 and Direct3D 10:
> >
> > Direct3D 10 supports one additional sampler type: *SamplerComparisonState*.

I get the feeling that contrary to this writeup, `SamplerState` is DX10 only. Virtually all the code I see uses `sampler_state` for *SamplerType*. A quick example from BasicHLSL (DX9):

```
sampler MeshTextureSampler =
sampler_state
{
    Texture = <g_MeshTexture>;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    MinFilter = LINEAR;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
};
```

Why do all the different _SamplerType_s exist and when would you use, say, `sampler` or `sampler2D` instead of `sampler_state`? You need to be explicit when fetching anyhow, e.g. `tex2D`, `texCUBE`, so what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. That is very odd.

It seems as if the documentation on the DirectX 9 syntax is wrong. I'm by no means an expert on either HLSL or DirectX, but I've always only seen samplers in DirectX 9 being declared like this:

```
SamplerType Name = sampler_state{   Texture = <texture_variable>;   [state_name = state_value;]   ... };
```

I might be missing something but to me the above syntax makes more sense than the one in the documentation. You declare a sampler with a given type, and specifies the sampler state.

**UPDATE:** Apparently it IS wrong. I've started [a thread on the official forums](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/37331.aspx) and so far I've only gotten a confirmation that it is wrong. I've also sent a mail directly to the DirectX team. Just to be on the safe side.

Comment: be warned, directx@microsoft.com is not actively monitored.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. Well I've also rated and provided feedback to the article in question, so maybe that'll work.

Comment: Thanks, glad I haven't lost it. I managed to dig out my old DX9 CHM and it had a much cleaner article. DX9 even does support sampler arrays, but you'd never know that from the newly botched MSDN page.

Answer (score 0):

sampler Name = SamplerType { Texture = ; [state_name = state_value;]};

It is correct!
The declaration is valid only for effects.

EDIT: the official forums are on MSDN. You can post a suggestion or an error using "Community Additions".